# How to load input from keyboard into an array in 8086?

Tags: string, assembly, io, x86-16

I am practicing Input and Output of strings in assembly language - `8086` environment. I came across the following code:

```
 org 100h

 .DATA

 SNAME DB 21,0,22 DUP('$')
 .CODE

 MOV AH, 0AH
 LEA DX, SNAME  

 INT 21H
 MOV AH, 9H
 LEA DX, SNAME +2;
 INT 21H
 ret
```

I know the program accepts input as a string from the keyboard and displays it on the screen. **However,I am  missing two things here**:

1. How do we tell that the user input is to be **stored** in variable `SNAME`? Does the instruction `LEA` make the program know that? I have asked this because in high level languages we could say `SNAME=someUserInput;` - here I am not seeing an `MOV SMANE,someUserInput;`
2. Why are we adding `2` in this instaruction `LEA DX,SNAME +2`?

Comment: If you look at how buffered input is done you'll see that _DX_ contains the address of the buffer with _int 21h_ / ah = 0ah_ . The SNAME+2 is when printing the buffer with _int 21h_ / ah = 09h_ . The actual string returned by the input command is preceded by two bytes that need to be skipped. For information on the dos input command see: http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do we tell that the user input is to be stored in variable SNAME?

Because your program uses the DOS input function 0Ah that requires you to setup a buffer to recieve the inputted characters. The byte at offset 0 must specify how many bytes you got available starting at offset 2. Specifying **21** means that you'll be able to input **20** characters. The extra byte will be filled with a carriage return (ASCII 13).

> Why are we adding 2 in this instaruction LEA DX,SNAME +2?

The DOS input function stores the inputted characters starting at offset 2 within the buffer that you specified. At offset 1 you'll find a byte containing the number of characters that were inputted. Behind these inputted characters DOS adds a carriage return (ASCII 13). This means that printing the way you did will inevitably leave the cursor at the start of the line.

Comment: Well, that is straight to the point - now I am seeing, thanks.